# How to unit test in ScriptSharp

Tags: unit-testing, qunit, script#

We noticed that there was a unit testing project within the latest Script# 0.8 code on the Git repository, but there is no documentation as to how to actually use it, and the example files don't seem to work correctly.

Having stepped through the source code, we can't actually see any test code within the unit test files.

Has anyone else managed to successfully run unit tests against Script# within the Visual Studio IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The AroundMe sample at https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/samples/AroundMe demonstrates unit testing.

In short, there are two parts -
1. The Tests subnamespace within your project containing tests alongside code being tested. Test code gets split out by the compiler to generate a Foo.test.js alongside Foo.js and Foo.debug.js.

1. A test project which provides a driver to launch unit tests in browser and capture results of QUnit to surface into VS unit testing UI. This is optional... you could run the Foo.test.js manually using QUnit yourself if you've got your own pipeline for executing tests.

Hope that helps.